# Uploading new app version after expiration of provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, provisioning

I visited many threads **over Stack Overflow about Provisioning Profile** before posting this question, but didn't get any satisfied opinion.

My Problem is that I have one of my clients app **version 1.0** live but its **Provisioning Profile is expired few months back.**

[image]

Now I want to upload the **new version 2.0** but I **don't have existing p12**, I only have is Credentials for developer account.

**Following are my Queries:**

1) Should I DELETE the existing expired certificates.

2) If I delete these existing certificates will it affect the existing customers those who are using this app.

3) As I mentioned earlier that I DON'T HAVE ANY EXISTING P12 not any other certificate, SO CAN I CREATE ALL THE WAY NEW CSR and P12.

**4) After uploading NEW VERSION 2.0 with newly created certificates will the existing customers get an update after app gets live.**

Regards.

Comment: Yes go ahead. It will work just make sure you don't change app identifier thats the only thing that identifies your app in app store.. See this https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG6 and this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2671101?threadID=2671101

Comment: @iphonic Means only concern is that "app identifier" must be same as previous rt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, create new certificates. Existing users will not be affected (you need to create new certificates every year). They will get updates to your new version (assuming you don't change the bundle identifier - i.e. you release a version upgrade for the same app).

Comment: Thanks wain +1 for quick response, will check it now, and get back to you.

Comment: I have a build live in appstore. I need to renew the certificate alone. For this case If I create a certificate with same bundle id shall i need to upload new build with the created certificate?

Answer (score 1):

1] revoke distribution certificate 
2] edit distribution provisioning profile 
3] download both 
4] and create build using new certificate

It will not affect previous app in Appstore

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your Queries:

1) YES, You can revoke all your certificates/profiles using your developer account credentials.

2) NO, doing so will not affect any existing customers.

3) YES, you can create all of them from scratch. All you need is account credentials. EXISTING P12 or  any other certificate are not required to Revoke.

4) YES. Make sure the bundle identifier is same.

Comment: will the same work if its developer certificate instead of distribution.

Comment: yes. however you can not publish (adhoc or appstore) without a distribution certificate.